# node.js - indexing elasticsearch documents - till infity

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm pretty new to Node.js - and hope not to ask to dumb questions...

I'm trying to index a document into elasticsearch - which works.

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

function writetoela(information){
    var client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'server03:9200'
    });

    client.index({
        index: 'fhem',
        type: 'state',
        body: {
             time: information.time,
             alias: information.alias,
             state: information.state,
             room: information.room
        }
    })}
```

My problems start after the indexing the document. The function won't exit, so I can do other stuff.

The function above is called by the following line:

```
index_data.writetoela(data);
```

'data' is a array of values, which should be indexed to elasticsearch.

Can somebody advise me, why this is happening?

Thanks you

Bjoern

Comment: Hi - just wondering if you managed to figure out why the function never returns? I am experiencing the same problem and I have no idea why. I have tested on both Windows and Ubuntu and same problem occurs.

Comment: Dear @M.Y., I've ended up using the REST API of elasticsearch with [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html)... works pretty straight forward, you just have to read through the docs of the REST API of elasticsearch... (They provide examples...).

Answer (score 0):

For me it should look like that:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

  function writetoela(information){
    var client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'server03:9200'
    });

    client.index({
        index: 'fhem',
        type: 'state',
        body: {
             time: information.time,
             alias: information.alias,
             state: information.state,
             room: information.room
        }
    }, function (err, resp) {
          // handle the error response here
          console.info(err);
          console.info(resp);
  });
```

For debugging your application use nodeinspector:
https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector